# PaaS that allows C++ code execution from PHP?

Tags: php, c++, cloud, paas, iaas

I have a web app written in PHP that shell_exec()'s a program written in C++ (which does some intensive calculations and returns a result back to PHP).

Do you know which PaaS providers allow this?

Comment: I've modified the question to have an objective enumerated answer without opinion. I respectfully request that the moderators consider reopening this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at OpenShift by Red Hat? They have powerful customization capabilities (with scripts and such things) that allow you to do just about anything. Look for "action hooks". It's one of the mechanisms that allow you to customize your environment when certain events occur. For example, I used an action hook to install a custom version of Node.js upon application startup in order to circumvent the limitations of the pre-installed Node.js. You can certainly do the same with PHP.

[OpenShift by Red Hat](https://www.openshift.com/)

**Edit**

I once was going to use it to develop a Node.js application that included a custom Node.js extension written in C++.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, Kevin. I have looked into OpenShift, but each gear is limited to 6 GB of storage, and I need something bigger for the database. Nevertheless, thank you for confirming this option! Do you happen to know of any other PaaS providers where this may be possible?

Comment: Not really, I remember looking hard for this type of PaaS and it is the only one I found. But maybe there are others. Maybe you could pay for more memory? (I know, it's not an ideal solution)

Comment: Yeah, ditto. Thanks again. I'll credit you with the answer later if I don't receive any viable alternatives. (Sorry that I forgot to mention OpenShift in my question! I dismissed it in my mind after reading about the 6 GB per gear limitation.) That said, any alternatives that allows for a larger database size (on disk, not memory) would be very helpful. Thank you everyone.

Comment: If I see something I'll let you know.

Comment: I guess you win the prize, Kevin! :) This seems to be a legitimate problem. I'm not trying to create an opinionated flame war; I believe this is a serious question. See also: [Pagoda Box | shell_exec Permission Denied](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/questions/108418-shell-exec-permission-denied)

Comment: Thank you :) I think that maybe they decided to put it on hold because it is not a problem directly related to programming. It is definitely a legitimate problem, though.